# Create a horizontal legend in a split map

Tags: google-earth-engine

Do you know how to get a horizontal legend in a split map in GEE? I already have the legend, but in vertical. I would like to know if there is any way to transform the legend to a horizontal one.

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d0fb69c5abd1fdedff4b9c38d1926dae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `longitude` image component of `ee.Image.pixelLonLat()` for the legend, e.g. `ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('longitude');` and change parameters of legend `ui.Thumbnail` object to better suit horizontal object, e.g. `{bbox:'0,0,100,10', dimensions:'100x15'}`
Here's [a quick sketch based on your code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7746e7de33cfea77dbf7dc78631dd804)